# How to organize big projects in the Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi

I would like to split my big application in smaller pieces in the IDE. Corrently, I have one project (MainApp.exe) with a lot of files. With so many files, I get sometimes confused where to find the right file to modify.
It would be great, if I could split my application in different parts, e.g. InvoicePart, AnalysisPart, CustomerPart, ReportPart, etc. When compiling the parts should be generate one executable file. That means I don't want to split the running *.exe application in DLLs or runtiume Packages. It should just help me writing code easier.

Is there an elegant way in Delphi XE?

Comment: Why not organize the source files into a tree (Invoice,Analysis, etc)? Your project manager will reflect this tree.

Comment: @LURD, by "tree" do you mean folders?

Comment: @UweRaabe, yes that is what I mean (directory-tree).

Comment: How many units in your project? One big exe is invariably the most convenient approach. Resist any attempt to make DLLs. Yuch! Grouping in folders is a sensible approach.

Comment: I let the IDE handle that for me. If you put your mouse pointer over a method/function/variable/type, Code Insight (part of the code editor) will show you the unit name and other info, and right-clicking and choosing `Find Declaration` from the context menu will open the right file (or switch to it if it's open already). That functionality, combined with naming conventions for your units (eg., 'InvoiceClasses`, `InvoiceProcessing`, `AnalysisClasses`, `ReportsInventory`, `ReportsInvoices`, etc.) along with the Project Manager's treeview make things pretty easy.

Comment: @LURD please make your first comment (creating a directory tree) an answer, as it is the most sensible approach. We use this all the time for big projects and it works like a charm.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers, ok made an answer of my comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Organize your source files in folders, like `(Invoice, Analysis, etc.)`. Navigate the folders through your `Project Manager` menu.

This is a straight forward uncomplicated and flexible approach.

Comment: +1 as it is the most sensible approach. We use this all the time for big projects and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, but it's far from elegant.

All you have to do is, split the files up into different directories. Say common, invoice analysis etc. Knock up a project for each one, and put the other directories in the search path in project options.
However, this is the fastest way to get into a complete mess I've ever seen. 
You can easily end up with different results depending on what order you build the sub projects in.

First which project should each file be in?

How will you stop having one file in more than one project.

Are you going to have a common folder for dcu files, several or none?

How do you know said object file has been compiled in the project that "owned" it? Object 
file out of step with the code is classic head scratcher.

If you use integrated source control how do you know everything relevant is up to date?

You could use a program group to keep all of them in sync, but that doesn't solve many of the other problems.

Basically if your single project has got so big you have this problem, you've totally lost control of it. The above will not regain control it will simply make it less obvious that you are in a tip.

Use dlls, it's what they are for. I know it won't be easy and it will cost you, but there's the right way to do it, your current mess, and your proposed mess. Bite the bullet and do it properly or leave it alone would be the only options I would choose from.

We ended up where you are proposing to go, it's not a happy place to be.

Comment: DLLs just create a huge overhead of writing imports. Which the compiler can't check for correctness. A single exe is always the most convenient solution for development.

Comment: And I've no idea what you mean by creating a separate project for each folder. A project has a one to one mapping with an executable. There's only one executable here, and so only one project.

Comment: DLLs are a terrible idea if your app is entirely Delphi. As David says, it means you have to write the imports, classes are more difficult to use in multiple places (without ShareMem), etc. If you're going to separate things out, at least do it properly and use runtime packages. (Although separating things out without a solid reason to do so is a bad idea, IMO, such as having several executables that share the same base classes but implement different parts of functionality, or you have a plug-in type architecture or optional modules.)

Comment: Separating things out without a solid reason to do so? How about your source code is unmanageable? How about it's not modular? Runtime package instead of dlls, fine. The point is when it gets too big break it up. Choose a method that suits you, or leave it alone and live with the pain. Re-engineering for either in a code base you've lost control of isn't going to be a quick and simple exercise. Run time package or dll is likely to be the entire thing.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend multiple projects to one exe as it doesn't really help, but set the name and a common folder to build the exe to, and job done. 1-1 is the out of the box option. The way we ended up was we have multiple projects building multiple exes but sharing the same code base(s), equally me3ssy I assure you.

Comment: The fact that you have multiple projects is not relevant to the question asked.

Comment: Packages/DLLs are not the solution for organizing source code. They are for plugin functionality. If your plugin solution is Delphi/C++Builder-only, then you should try to avoid DLLs and go for Packages.